# Trying to add a url with value into a php based drop down list

Tags: php

I have been working on this problem for a few hours and cannot seem to figure this out.  It is adding the rest of my code to the echo and I don't know how to stop it, I have tried a variety of different things including making the url its own variable and just calling that in the echo, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
      <?php

    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    $apikey = "---------------------------";  /* put your API key here */ 
    $apiparse= "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=";
    $idparse= "&steamids=";
    $playersummary="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' .$apikey. '&steamids=' .$keyword. ";

    /* -------------------- */

    echo'<form name="selectoption">';
    echo'<select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">';
    echo'<option selected="selected">Select One</option>';
    echo'<option value="'.$playersummary.'">Player Summary</option>';
    echo'<option value="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=' .$apikey. '&steamid=' .$keyword. '&relationship=friend">Friends</option>';
    echo'<option value="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=440&key=' .$apikey. '&steamid=' .$keyword. ">Achievements</option>';
    echo'</select>';
    echo'</form>';

    ?>
```

Comment: What are you asking? It isn't clear what your issue is, or what you have you tried.

Comment: From the syntax highlighting here it becomes obvious immediately that you messed up the string delimiters in your third-last `echo` statement – after `'&steamid=' .$keyword.` an additional `'` is needed before the following `">Achievements…` (Not sure if that is what you were asking about though, because _“It is adding the rest of my code to the echo”_ could mean any number of things – so next time, please be more specific in your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, replace `"` with `'` in line 18.
Secondly, slowly explain what you are asking for and what you are trying to do.

```
<?php

$keyword = "sdasdas";
$apikey = "---------------------------";  /* put your API key here */ 
$apiparse= "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=";
$idparse= "&steamids=";
$playersummary="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' .$apikey. '&steamids=' .$keyword. ";

/* -------------------- */

echo'<form name="selectoption">';
echo'<select name="menu" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">';
echo'<option selected="selected">Select One</option>';
echo'<option value="'.$playersummary.'">Player Summary</option>';
echo'<option value="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=' .$apikey. '&steamid=' .$keyword. '&relationship=friend">Friends</option>';
echo'<option value="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=440&key=' .$apikey. '&steamid=' .$keyword. '>Achievements</option>';
echo'</select>';
echo'</form>';
```